Show all data in chartjs
I've got some issue where I can't show all data which is the date and time.
I want the chart height to be at least take 80% of the screen height, allow horizontal scroll so that they will not be compressed and all date and time should be entirely visible.


// Helper function to parse CSV data
function parseCSV(csv) {
  const lines = csv.split("\n");
  const temperatures = [];
  const timestamps = [];

  lines.forEach((line) => {
    const [temperature, timestamp] = line.split(",");
    if (temperature && timestamp) {
      temperatures.push(parseFloat(temperature).toFixed(2)); // Round temperature to 2 decimal places
      timestamps.push(new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString()); // Format timestamp
    }
  });

  return { temperatures, timestamps };
}

// Function to create the line chart
function createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById("temperatureChart").getContext("2d");

  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: {
      labels: timestamps,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Temperature (°C)",
          data: temperatures,
          borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
          backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          fill: true,
          tension: 0.1,
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Time",
          },
        },
        y: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Temperature (°C)",
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
}

const csv = `24.6333332,2024-08-01 12:13:29
24.2333335,2024-08-01 12:14:29
24.0333328,2024-08-01 12:15:29
23.8000011,2024-08-01 12:16:34
30.7000007,2024-08-01 12:17:33
27.7666664,2024-08-01 12:18:33
26.2333335,2024-08-01 12:19:33
25.3000011,2024-08-01 12:20:33
24.6666679,2024-08-01 12:21:33
24.3999996,2024-08-01 12:22:33
24.1666679,2024-08-01 12:23:33
24.0000000,2024-08-01 12:24:33
23.8999996,2024-08-01 12:25:33
23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:26:33
23.6666679,2024-08-01 12:27:33
23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:28:33
23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:29:33
23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:30:33
23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:31:33
23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:32:33
23.5666656,2024-08-01 12:33:34
23.6000003,2024-08-01 12:34:33
23.6333332,2024-08-01 12:35:33
23.6666660,2024-08-01 12:36:33
23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:37:33
23.8000011,2024-08-01 12:38:33
23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:39:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:40:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:41:33
23.9333343,2024-08-01 12:42:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:43:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:44:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:45:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:46:33
23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:47:33
23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:48:33
23.9333343,2024-08-01 12:49:33
23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:50:33
23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:51:33
23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:52:33
23.7333335,2024-08-01 12:53:33
23.7333335,2024-08-01 12:54:33
23.6666679,2024-08-01 12:55:33
23.5666675,2024-08-01 12:56:33
23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:57:33
21.8000011,2024-08-01 14:37:23
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:37:33
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:38:33
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:39:33
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:40:33
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:41:33
21.7333335,2024-08-01 14:42:33
21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:43:33
21.7333335,2024-08-01 14:44:33
21.7000007,2024-08-01 14:45:33
21.7000007,2024-08-01 14:46:33
21.6666660,2024-08-01 14:47:33
21.6333332,2024-08-01 14:48:33
21.5666675,2024-08-01 14:49:33
21.5666675,2024-08-01 14:50:33
21.5333328,2024-08-01 14:51:33
21.5666675,2024-08-01 14:52:33
21.4666671,2024-08-01 14:53:33
21.4666671,2024-08-01 14:54:33
21.4666671,2024-08-01 14:55:33
21.3000011,2024-08-01 14:56:33
21.3000011,2024-08-01 14:57:33
21.3000011,2024-08-01 14:58:33
21.2000007,2024-08-01 14:59:33
21.2000007,2024-08-01 15:00:33
21.1000003,2024-08-01 15:01:33
21.1000003,2024-08-01 15:02:33
21.0666675,2024-08-01 15:03:33
21.0666675,2024-08-01 15:04:33
21.0666675,2024-08-01 15:05:33
21.0333347,2024-08-01 15:06:33
20.9666671,2024-08-01 15:07:33
20.9000015,2024-08-01 15:08:33
20.9000015,2024-08-01 15:09:33
20.8666667,2024-08-01 15:10:33
20.8666667,2024-08-01 15:11:33
20.7666664,2024-08-01 15:12:33
20.7666664,2024-08-01 15:13:33
20.6666660,2024-08-01 15:14:33
18.1666679,2024-08-02 00:03:24
18.2333335,2024-08-02 00:03:33
18.2666664,2024-08-02 00:04:33
18.3333339,2024-08-02 00:05:33
18.3666667,2024-08-02 00:06:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 00:07:33
18.5666675,2024-08-02 00:08:33
18.6666660,2024-08-02 00:09:33
18.6333332,2024-08-02 00:10:33
18.7000007,2024-08-02 00:11:35
18.7333335,2024-08-02 00:12:33
18.7666664,2024-08-02 00:13:33
18.8000011,2024-08-02 00:14:33
18.8000011,2024-08-02 00:15:33
18.9333343,2024-08-02 00:16:33
18.9333343,2024-08-02 00:17:33
18.9666671,2024-08-02 00:18:33
19.0333347,2024-08-02 00:19:33
19.0666675,2024-08-02 00:20:33
19.1000003,2024-08-02 00:21:33
19.1666660,2024-08-02 00:22:33
19.1666660,2024-08-02 00:23:33
19.2333335,2024-08-02 00:24:33
19.2666664,2024-08-02 00:25:33
19.3666667,2024-08-02 00:26:33
19.3000011,2024-08-02 00:27:33
19.4000015,2024-08-02 00:28:33
19.4000015,2024-08-02 00:29:33
19.4333343,2024-08-02 00:30:33
19.5333347,2024-08-02 00:31:33
19.5333347,2024-08-02 00:32:33
19.5666675,2024-08-02 00:33:33
19.5666675,2024-08-02 00:34:33
19.6333332,2024-08-02 00:35:33
19.7000007,2024-08-02 00:36:33
19.6666660,2024-08-02 00:37:33
19.8000011,2024-08-02 00:38:33
19.8333339,2024-08-02 00:39:33
19.8666667,2024-08-02 00:40:33
19.8999996,2024-08-02 00:41:33
19.9666671,2024-08-02 00:42:33
19.9666671,2024-08-02 00:43:33
20.0666675,2024-08-02 00:44:33
20.0666675,2024-08-02 00:45:33
20.1000003,2024-08-02 00:46:33
20.1000003,2024-08-02 00:47:33
20.2000007,2024-08-02 00:48:33
20.2000007,2024-08-02 00:49:33
20.2333335,2024-08-02 00:50:33
20.2333335,2024-08-02 00:51:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 00:52:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 00:53:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:54:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:55:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:56:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:57:33
20.4333343,2024-08-02 00:58:33
20.5000000,2024-08-02 00:59:33
20.5000000,2024-08-02 01:00:33
20.5333328,2024-08-02 01:01:33
20.5666675,2024-08-02 01:02:33
20.6333332,2024-08-02 01:03:33
20.6666679,2024-08-02 01:04:33
20.7333335,2024-08-02 01:05:33
20.7333335,2024-08-02 01:06:33
20.8666667,2024-08-02 01:07:33
20.9333343,2024-08-02 01:08:33
20.9666671,2024-08-02 01:09:33
20.9666671,2024-08-02 01:10:33
21.0666675,2024-08-02 01:11:33
21.1333332,2024-08-02 01:12:33
21.1333332,2024-08-02 01:13:33
21.2000007,2024-08-02 01:14:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 01:15:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 01:16:33
21.3333339,2024-08-02 01:17:33
21.3999996,2024-08-02 01:18:33
21.4333343,2024-08-02 01:19:33
21.4666671,2024-08-02 01:20:33
21.4666671,2024-08-02 01:21:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:22:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:23:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:24:33
21.6666679,2024-08-02 01:25:33
21.7333335,2024-08-02 01:26:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 01:27:33
21.7999992,2024-08-02 01:28:33
21.8333339,2024-08-02 01:29:33
21.8333339,2024-08-02 01:30:33
21.8999996,2024-08-02 01:31:33
21.9333343,2024-08-02 01:32:33
22.0000000,2024-08-02 01:33:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 01:34:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 01:35:33
22.0666675,2024-08-02 01:36:33
22.1000003,2024-08-02 01:37:33
22.1000003,2024-08-02 01:38:33
22.2000007,2024-08-02 01:39:33
22.2000007,2024-08-02 01:40:33
22.2333335,2024-08-02 01:41:33
22.3000011,2024-08-02 01:42:33
22.3999996,2024-08-02 01:43:33
22.3999996,2024-08-02 01:44:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 01:45:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 01:46:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 01:47:33
22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:48:33
22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:49:33
22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:50:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 01:51:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 01:52:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 01:53:33
22.7666664,2024-08-02 01:54:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 01:55:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 01:56:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:57:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:58:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:59:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:00:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:01:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:02:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:03:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:04:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:05:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:06:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:07:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:08:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:09:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:10:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:11:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:12:33
23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:13:33
23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:14:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:15:33
23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:16:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:17:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:18:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:19:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:20:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:21:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:22:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:23:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 02:24:33
23.1666679,2024-08-02 02:25:33
23.1666679,2024-08-02 02:26:33
23.2000007,2024-08-02 02:27:33
23.2000007,2024-08-02 02:28:33
23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:29:33
23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:30:33
23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:31:33
23.2999992,2024-08-02 02:32:33
23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:33:33
23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:34:33
23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:35:33
23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:36:33
23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:37:33
23.3333339,2024-08-02 02:38:33
23.3333339,2024-08-02 02:39:33
23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:40:33
23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:41:33
23.3999996,2024-08-02 02:42:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:43:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:44:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 02:45:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:46:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:47:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:48:33
23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:49:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:50:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:51:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:52:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:53:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 02:54:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:55:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:56:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:57:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 02:58:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:59:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:00:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:01:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:02:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:03:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:04:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:05:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:06:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 03:07:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:08:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:09:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:10:33
23.4333343,2024-08-02 03:11:33
23.3666667,2024-08-02 03:12:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:13:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:14:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:15:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:16:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:17:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 03:18:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 03:19:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 03:20:33
23.6666660,2024-08-02 03:21:33
23.6666679,2024-08-02 03:22:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 03:23:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:24:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:25:33
23.7666683,2024-08-02 03:26:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:27:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:28:33
23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:29:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:30:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:31:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:32:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:33:33
23.7333335,2024-08-02 03:34:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:35:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:36:33
23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:37:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:38:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:39:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:40:33
23.8999996,2024-08-02 03:41:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:42:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:43:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:44:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:45:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:46:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:47:33
23.8999996,2024-08-02 03:48:33
23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:49:33
23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:50:33
23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:51:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:52:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:53:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:54:33
23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:55:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:56:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:57:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:58:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:59:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:00:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:01:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:02:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:03:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:04:33
23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:05:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:06:33
23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:07:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:08:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:09:33
23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:10:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:11:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:12:33
23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:13:33
23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:14:33
23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:15:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:16:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:17:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:18:33
23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:19:33
23.6666679,2024-08-02 04:20:33
23.6666679,2024-08-02 04:21:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:22:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:23:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:24:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:25:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:26:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:27:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:28:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:29:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:30:33
23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:31:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:32:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:33:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:34:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:35:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:36:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:37:33
23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:38:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:39:33
23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:40:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:41:33
23.5333328,2024-08-02 04:42:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:43:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:44:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:45:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:46:33
23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:47:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:48:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:49:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:50:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:51:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:52:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:53:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:54:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:55:33
23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:56:33
23.4333343,2024-08-02 04:57:33
23.3999996,2024-08-02 04:58:33
23.3333339,2024-08-02 04:59:33
23.3333339,2024-08-02 05:00:33
23.3000011,2024-08-02 05:01:33
23.3000011,2024-08-02 05:02:33
23.2333335,2024-08-02 05:03:33
23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:04:33
23.2333335,2024-08-02 05:05:33
23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:06:33
23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:07:33
23.1666679,2024-08-02 05:08:33
23.1666679,2024-08-02 05:09:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:10:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:11:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:12:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:13:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:14:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:15:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:16:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:17:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:18:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:19:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:20:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:21:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:22:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:23:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:24:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:25:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:26:33
23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:27:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:28:33
23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:29:33
23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:30:33
23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:31:33
23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:32:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:33:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:34:33
23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:35:33
23.0000000,2024-08-02 05:36:33
23.0000000,2024-08-02 05:37:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:38:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:39:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:40:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:41:33
22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:42:33
22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:43:33
22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:44:33
22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:45:33
22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:46:33
22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:47:33
22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:48:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:49:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:50:33
22.8333339,2024-08-02 05:51:33
22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:52:33
22.8333339,2024-08-02 05:53:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:54:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:55:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:56:33
22.7666664,2024-08-02 05:57:33
22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:58:34
22.7333335,2024-08-02 05:59:33
22.7333335,2024-08-02 06:00:33
22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:01:33
22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:02:33
22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:03:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:04:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:05:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:06:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:07:33
22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:08:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:09:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:10:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:11:33
22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:12:33
22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:13:33
22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:14:33
22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:15:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:16:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:17:34
22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:18:33
22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:19:33
22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:20:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:21:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:22:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:23:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:24:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:25:33
22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:26:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:27:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:28:33
22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:29:33
22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:30:33
22.4000015,2024-08-02 06:31:33
22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:32:33
22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:33:33
22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:34:33
22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:35:33
22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:36:33
22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:37:33
22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:38:33
22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:39:33
22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:40:33
22.2333335,2024-08-02 06:41:33
22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:42:33
22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:43:33
22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:44:33
22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:45:33
22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:46:33
22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:47:33
22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:48:33
22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:49:33
22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:50:33
22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:51:33
22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:52:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:53:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:54:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:55:33
22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:56:33
22.0000000,2024-08-02 06:57:33
21.9666671,2024-08-02 06:58:33
21.9666671,2024-08-02 06:59:33
21.9666671,2024-08-02 07:00:33
22.0000000,2024-08-02 07:01:33
21.9333343,2024-08-02 07:02:33
21.9000015,2024-08-02 07:03:33
21.9666671,2024-08-02 07:04:33
21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:05:33
21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:06:33
21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:07:33
21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:08:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:09:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:10:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:11:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:12:33
21.8000011,2024-08-02 07:13:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:14:33
21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:15:33
21.7000007,2024-08-02 07:16:33
21.7333335,2024-08-02 07:17:33
21.7000007,2024-08-02 07:18:33
21.6666660,2024-08-02 07:19:33
21.6000003,2024-08-02 07:20:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:21:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:22:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:23:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:24:33
21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:25:33
21.5333328,2024-08-02 07:26:33
21.5333328,2024-08-02 07:27:33
21.4666671,2024-08-02 07:28:33
21.5000000,2024-08-02 07:29:33
21.4666671,2024-08-02 07:30:33
21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:31:33
21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:32:33
21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:33:33
21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:34:33
21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:35:33
21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:36:33
21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:37:33
21.3000011,2024-08-02 07:38:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:39:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:40:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:41:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:42:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:43:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:44:33
21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:45:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:46:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:47:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:48:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:49:33
21.1333332,2024-08-02 07:50:33
21.1333332,2024-08-02 07:51:33
21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:52:33
21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:53:33
21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:54:33
21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:55:33
21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:56:33
21.0666675,2024-08-02 07:57:33
21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:58:33
21.0333328,2024-08-02 07:59:33
21.0333328,2024-08-02 08:00:33
20.9666671,2024-08-02 08:01:33
20.9666671,2024-08-02 08:02:33
20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:03:33
20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:04:33
20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:05:33
20.8666667,2024-08-02 08:06:33
20.8333339,2024-08-02 08:07:33
20.8333339,2024-08-02 08:08:33
20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:09:33
20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:10:33
20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:11:33
20.6666660,2024-08-02 08:12:33
20.6666660,2024-08-02 08:13:33
20.5666675,2024-08-02 08:14:33
20.5666675,2024-08-02 08:15:33
20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:16:33
20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:17:33
20.5000000,2024-08-02 08:18:33
20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:19:33
20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:20:33
20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:21:33
20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:22:33
20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:23:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 08:24:33
20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:25:33
20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:26:33
20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:27:33
20.3666667,2024-08-02 08:28:33
20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:29:33
20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:30:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:31:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:32:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:33:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:34:33
20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:35:33
20.1666660,2024-08-02 08:36:33
20.1666660,2024-08-02 08:37:33
20.1333332,2024-08-02 08:38:33
20.1333332,2024-08-02 08:39:33
20.0666675,2024-08-02 08:40:33
20.0666675,2024-08-02 08:41:33
19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:42:33
19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:43:33
19.9333343,2024-08-02 08:44:33
19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:45:33
19.9000015,2024-08-02 08:46:33
19.8666667,2024-08-02 08:47:33
19.8000011,2024-08-02 08:48:33
19.7666664,2024-08-02 08:49:33
19.7333335,2024-08-02 08:50:33
19.6666660,2024-08-02 08:51:33
19.6666660,2024-08-02 08:52:33
19.6000003,2024-08-02 08:53:33
19.6000003,2024-08-02 08:54:33
19.5666675,2024-08-02 08:55:33
19.5333347,2024-08-02 08:56:33
19.5333347,2024-08-02 08:57:33
19.5000000,2024-08-02 08:58:33
19.4333343,2024-08-02 08:59:33
19.4333343,2024-08-02 09:00:33
19.4666671,2024-08-02 09:01:33
19.4333343,2024-08-02 09:02:33
19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:03:33
19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:04:33
19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:05:33
19.3333339,2024-08-02 09:06:33
19.3000011,2024-08-02 09:07:33
19.2666664,2024-08-02 09:08:33
19.2666664,2024-08-02 09:09:33
19.2000007,2024-08-02 09:10:33
19.1666660,2024-08-02 09:11:33
19.1666679,2024-08-02 09:12:33
19.1333332,2024-08-02 09:13:33
19.1333332,2024-08-02 09:14:33
19.0666675,2024-08-02 09:15:33
19.0333328,2024-08-02 09:16:33
19.0333328,2024-08-02 09:17:33
18.9666671,2024-08-02 09:18:33
19.0000000,2024-08-02 09:19:33
18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:20:33
18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:21:33
18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:22:33
18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:23:33
18.8333339,2024-08-02 09:24:33
18.8333339,2024-08-02 09:25:33
18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:26:33
18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:27:33
18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:28:33
18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:29:33
18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:30:33
18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:31:33
18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:32:33
18.6666660,2024-08-02 09:33:33
18.6333332,2024-08-02 09:34:33
18.6333332,2024-08-02 09:35:33
18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:36:33
18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:37:33
18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:38:33
18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:39:33
18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:40:33
18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:41:33
18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:42:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:43:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:44:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:45:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:46:33
18.4000015,2024-08-02 09:47:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:48:33
18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:49:33
18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:50:33
18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:51:33
18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:52:33
18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:53:33
18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:54:33
18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:55:33
18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:56:33
18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:57:33
18.2000007,2024-08-02 09:58:33
18.2000007,2024-08-02 09:59:33
18.1333332,2024-08-02 10:00:33
18.1333332,2024-08-02 10:01:33`;

// data is originally from csv
// // Fetch and process the CSV data
// fetch("data.csv")
//   .then((response) => response.text())
//   .then((csv) => {
//     const { temperatures, timestamps } = parseCSV(csv);
//     createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps);
//   });

function parseCSV(csv) {
  const rows = csv.trim().split("\n");
  const temperatures = [];
  const timestamps = [];

  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const [temp, timestamp] = row.split(",");
    temperatures.push(parseFloat(temp));
    timestamps.push(timestamp);
  });

  return { temperatures, timestamps };
}

const { temperatures, timestamps } = parseCSV(csv);
createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps);
.container {
    width: 100%;
}


.scrollable {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

canvas {
    width: 2000%;
    height: 400px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Temperature</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <!-- Header content -->
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="scrollable">
                <canvas id="temperatureChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
           <p></p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Chart.js CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0"></script>

    <!-- Link to external JavaScript -->
</body>
</html>



I'm really not sure where I am lacking. I've provided sample data so that we can see the POV and that can reach up to several thousands.

I found a solution what you need to do is add width: 300% to scrollable & width: 100% !important to canvas.
Thats all but remember increase width little by little like 100% - 200% - 300%, I applied 2000% width directly and it crashed codepen & chrome because of large amount of data.
Below is working example and open in fullscreen.


function parseCSV(csv) {
    const lines = csv.split("\n");
    const temperatures = [];
    const timestamps = [];
  
    lines.forEach((line) => {
      const [temperature, timestamp] = line.split(",");
      if (temperature && timestamp) {
        temperatures.push(parseFloat(temperature).toFixed(2)); // Round temperature to 2 decimal places
        timestamps.push(new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString()); // Format timestamp
      }
    });
  
    return { temperatures, timestamps };
  }
  
  // Function to create the line chart
  function createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("temperatureChart").getContext("2d");
  
    new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: timestamps,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Temperature (°C)",
            data: temperatures,
            borderColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            fill: true,
            tension: 0.1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Time",
            },
          },
          y: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Temperature (°C)",
            },
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
  
  const csv = `24.6333332,2024-08-01 12:13:29
  24.2333335,2024-08-01 12:14:29
  24.0333328,2024-08-01 12:15:29
  23.8000011,2024-08-01 12:16:34
  30.7000007,2024-08-01 12:17:33
  27.7666664,2024-08-01 12:18:33
  26.2333335,2024-08-01 12:19:33
  25.3000011,2024-08-01 12:20:33
  24.6666679,2024-08-01 12:21:33
  24.3999996,2024-08-01 12:22:33
  24.1666679,2024-08-01 12:23:33
  24.0000000,2024-08-01 12:24:33
  23.8999996,2024-08-01 12:25:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:26:33
  23.6666679,2024-08-01 12:27:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:28:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:29:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:30:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-01 12:31:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:32:33
  23.5666656,2024-08-01 12:33:34
  23.6000003,2024-08-01 12:34:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-01 12:35:33
  23.6666660,2024-08-01 12:36:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:37:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-01 12:38:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-01 12:39:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:40:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:41:33
  23.9333343,2024-08-01 12:42:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:43:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:44:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:45:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:46:33
  23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:47:33
  23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:48:33
  23.9333343,2024-08-01 12:49:33
  23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:50:33
  23.9000015,2024-08-01 12:51:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-01 12:52:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-01 12:53:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-01 12:54:33
  23.6666679,2024-08-01 12:55:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-01 12:56:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-01 12:57:33
  21.8000011,2024-08-01 14:37:23
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:37:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:38:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:39:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:40:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:41:33
  21.7333335,2024-08-01 14:42:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-01 14:43:33
  21.7333335,2024-08-01 14:44:33
  21.7000007,2024-08-01 14:45:33
  21.7000007,2024-08-01 14:46:33
  20.2333335,2024-08-02 00:51:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 00:52:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 00:53:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:54:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:55:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:56:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 00:57:33
  20.4333343,2024-08-02 00:58:33
  20.5000000,2024-08-02 00:59:33
  20.5000000,2024-08-02 01:00:33
  20.5333328,2024-08-02 01:01:33
  20.5666675,2024-08-02 01:02:33
  20.6333332,2024-08-02 01:03:33
  20.6666679,2024-08-02 01:04:33
  20.7333335,2024-08-02 01:05:33
  20.7333335,2024-08-02 01:06:33
  20.8666667,2024-08-02 01:07:33
  20.9333343,2024-08-02 01:08:33
  20.9666671,2024-08-02 01:09:33
  20.9666671,2024-08-02 01:10:33
  21.0666675,2024-08-02 01:11:33
  21.1333332,2024-08-02 01:12:33
  21.1333332,2024-08-02 01:13:33
  21.2000007,2024-08-02 01:14:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 01:15:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 01:16:33
  21.3333339,2024-08-02 01:17:33
  21.3999996,2024-08-02 01:18:33
  21.4333343,2024-08-02 01:19:33
  21.4666671,2024-08-02 01:20:33
  21.4666671,2024-08-02 01:21:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:22:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:23:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 01:24:33
  21.6666679,2024-08-02 01:25:33
  21.7333335,2024-08-02 01:26:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 01:27:33
  21.7999992,2024-08-02 01:28:33
  21.8333339,2024-08-02 01:29:33
  21.8333339,2024-08-02 01:30:33
  21.8999996,2024-08-02 01:31:33
  21.9333343,2024-08-02 01:32:33
  22.0000000,2024-08-02 01:33:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 01:34:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 01:35:33
  22.0666675,2024-08-02 01:36:33
  22.1000003,2024-08-02 01:37:33
  22.1000003,2024-08-02 01:38:33
  22.2000007,2024-08-02 01:39:33
  22.2000007,2024-08-02 01:40:33
  22.2333335,2024-08-02 01:41:33
  22.3000011,2024-08-02 01:42:33
  22.3999996,2024-08-02 01:43:33
  22.3999996,2024-08-02 01:44:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 01:45:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 01:46:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 01:47:33
  22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:48:33
  22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:49:33
  22.5666675,2024-08-02 01:50:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 01:51:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 01:52:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 01:53:33
  22.7666664,2024-08-02 01:54:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 01:55:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 01:56:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:57:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:58:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 01:59:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:00:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:01:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 02:02:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:03:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:04:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:05:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:06:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:07:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:08:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:09:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:10:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:11:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:12:33
  23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:13:33
  23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:14:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:15:33
  23.0000000,2024-08-02 02:16:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 02:17:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:18:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 02:19:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:20:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:21:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:22:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 02:23:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 02:24:33
  23.1666679,2024-08-02 02:25:33
  23.1666679,2024-08-02 02:26:33
  23.2000007,2024-08-02 02:27:33
  23.2000007,2024-08-02 02:28:33
  23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:29:33
  23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:30:33
  23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:31:33
  23.2999992,2024-08-02 02:32:33
  23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:33:33
  23.2666664,2024-08-02 02:34:33
  23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:35:33
  23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:36:33
  23.3666667,2024-08-02 02:37:33
  23.3333339,2024-08-02 02:38:33
  23.3333339,2024-08-02 02:39:33
  23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:40:33
  23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:41:33
  23.3999996,2024-08-02 02:42:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:43:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:44:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 02:45:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:46:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:47:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:48:33
  23.4333343,2024-08-02 02:49:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:50:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 02:51:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:52:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:53:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 02:54:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:55:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 02:56:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:57:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 02:58:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 02:59:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:00:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:01:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:02:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:03:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:04:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:05:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:06:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 03:07:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:08:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:09:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:10:33
  23.4333343,2024-08-02 03:11:33
  23.3666667,2024-08-02 03:12:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 03:13:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 03:14:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:15:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:16:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 03:17:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 03:18:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 03:19:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 03:20:33
  23.6666660,2024-08-02 03:21:33
  23.6666679,2024-08-02 03:22:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 03:23:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:24:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:25:33
  23.7666683,2024-08-02 03:26:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:27:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:28:33
  23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:29:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:30:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:31:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:32:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:33:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-02 03:34:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:35:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:36:33
  23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:37:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:38:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:39:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:40:33
  23.8999996,2024-08-02 03:41:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:42:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:43:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:44:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:45:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:46:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:47:33
  23.8999996,2024-08-02 03:48:33
  23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:49:33
  23.8666667,2024-08-02 03:50:33
  23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:51:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:52:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:53:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:54:33
  23.8333339,2024-08-02 03:55:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 03:56:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:57:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:58:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 03:59:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:00:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:01:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:02:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:03:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:04:33
  23.8000011,2024-08-02 04:05:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:06:33
  23.7666664,2024-08-02 04:07:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:08:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:09:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:10:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:11:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:12:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:13:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:14:33
  23.7333335,2024-08-02 04:15:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:16:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:17:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:18:33
  23.7000007,2024-08-02 04:19:33
  23.6666679,2024-08-02 04:20:33
  23.6666679,2024-08-02 04:21:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:22:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:23:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:24:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:25:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:26:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:27:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:28:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:29:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:30:33
  23.6333332,2024-08-02 04:31:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:32:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:33:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:34:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:35:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:36:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:37:33
  23.6000003,2024-08-02 04:38:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:39:33
  23.5666675,2024-08-02 04:40:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:41:33
  23.5333328,2024-08-02 04:42:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:43:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:44:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:45:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:46:33
  23.5000000,2024-08-02 04:47:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:48:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:49:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:50:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:51:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:52:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:53:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:54:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:55:33
  23.4666671,2024-08-02 04:56:33
  23.4333343,2024-08-02 04:57:33
  23.3999996,2024-08-02 04:58:33
  23.3333339,2024-08-02 04:59:33
  23.3333339,2024-08-02 05:00:33
  23.3000011,2024-08-02 05:01:33
  23.3000011,2024-08-02 05:02:33
  23.2333335,2024-08-02 05:03:33
  23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:04:33
  23.2333335,2024-08-02 05:05:33
  23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:06:33
  23.2000007,2024-08-02 05:07:33
  23.1666679,2024-08-02 05:08:33
  23.1666679,2024-08-02 05:09:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:10:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:11:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:12:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:13:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:14:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:15:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:16:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:17:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:18:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:19:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:20:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:21:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:22:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:23:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:24:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:25:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:26:33
  23.1333332,2024-08-02 05:27:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:28:33
  23.1000003,2024-08-02 05:29:33
  23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:30:33
  23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:31:33
  23.0666675,2024-08-02 05:32:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:33:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:34:33
  23.0333328,2024-08-02 05:35:33
  23.0000000,2024-08-02 05:36:33
  23.0000000,2024-08-02 05:37:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:38:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:39:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:40:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:41:33
  22.9333343,2024-08-02 05:42:33
  22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:43:33
  22.9666671,2024-08-02 05:44:33
  22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:45:33
  22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:46:33
  22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:47:33
  22.9000015,2024-08-02 05:48:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:49:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:50:33
  22.8333339,2024-08-02 05:51:33
  22.8666667,2024-08-02 05:52:33
  22.8333339,2024-08-02 05:53:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:54:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:55:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:56:33
  22.7666664,2024-08-02 05:57:33
  22.8000011,2024-08-02 05:58:34
  22.7333335,2024-08-02 05:59:33
  22.7333335,2024-08-02 06:00:33
  22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:01:33
  22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:02:33
  22.7666664,2024-08-02 06:03:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:04:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:05:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:06:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:07:33
  22.7000007,2024-08-02 06:08:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:09:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:10:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:11:33
  22.6333332,2024-08-02 06:12:33
  22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:13:33
  22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:14:33
  22.6000003,2024-08-02 06:15:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:16:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:17:34
  22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:18:33
  22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:19:33
  22.5333328,2024-08-02 06:20:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:21:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:22:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:23:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:24:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:25:33
  22.5000000,2024-08-02 06:26:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:27:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:28:33
  22.4666671,2024-08-02 06:29:33
  22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:30:33
  22.4000015,2024-08-02 06:31:33
  22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:32:33
  22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:33:33
  22.3666667,2024-08-02 06:34:33
  22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:35:33
  22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:36:33
  22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:37:33
  22.3333339,2024-08-02 06:38:33
  22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:39:33
  22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:40:33
  22.2333335,2024-08-02 06:41:33
  22.2666664,2024-08-02 06:42:33
  22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:43:33
  22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:44:33
  22.1666660,2024-08-02 06:45:33
  22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:46:33
  22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:47:33
  22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:48:33
  22.1333332,2024-08-02 06:49:33
  22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:50:33
  22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:51:33
  22.0666675,2024-08-02 06:52:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:53:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:54:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:55:33
  22.0333328,2024-08-02 06:56:33
  22.0000000,2024-08-02 06:57:33
  21.9666671,2024-08-02 06:58:33
  21.9666671,2024-08-02 06:59:33
  21.9666671,2024-08-02 07:00:33
  22.0000000,2024-08-02 07:01:33
  21.9333343,2024-08-02 07:02:33
  21.9000015,2024-08-02 07:03:33
  21.9666671,2024-08-02 07:04:33
  21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:05:33
  21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:06:33
  21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:07:33
  21.8666667,2024-08-02 07:08:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:09:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:10:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:11:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:12:33
  21.8000011,2024-08-02 07:13:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:14:33
  21.7666664,2024-08-02 07:15:33
  21.7000007,2024-08-02 07:16:33
  21.7333335,2024-08-02 07:17:33
  21.7000007,2024-08-02 07:18:33
  21.6666660,2024-08-02 07:19:33
  21.6000003,2024-08-02 07:20:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:21:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:22:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:23:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:24:33
  21.5666675,2024-08-02 07:25:33
  21.5333328,2024-08-02 07:26:33
  21.5333328,2024-08-02 07:27:33
  21.4666671,2024-08-02 07:28:33
  21.5000000,2024-08-02 07:29:33
  21.4666671,2024-08-02 07:30:33
  21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:31:33
  21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:32:33
  21.4333343,2024-08-02 07:33:33
  21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:34:33
  21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:35:33
  21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:36:33
  21.3666667,2024-08-02 07:37:33
  21.3000011,2024-08-02 07:38:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:39:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:40:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:41:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:42:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:43:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:44:33
  21.2666664,2024-08-02 07:45:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:46:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:47:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:48:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:49:33
  21.1333332,2024-08-02 07:50:33
  21.1333332,2024-08-02 07:51:33
  21.1666660,2024-08-02 07:52:33
  21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:53:33
  21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:54:33
  21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:55:33
  21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:56:33
  21.0666675,2024-08-02 07:57:33
  21.1000003,2024-08-02 07:58:33
  21.0333328,2024-08-02 07:59:33
  21.0333328,2024-08-02 08:00:33
  20.9666671,2024-08-02 08:01:33
  20.9666671,2024-08-02 08:02:33
  20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:03:33
  20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:04:33
  20.9333343,2024-08-02 08:05:33
  20.8666667,2024-08-02 08:06:33
  20.8333339,2024-08-02 08:07:33
  20.8333339,2024-08-02 08:08:33
  20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:09:33
  20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:10:33
  20.7333335,2024-08-02 08:11:33
  20.6666660,2024-08-02 08:12:33
  20.6666660,2024-08-02 08:13:33
  20.5666675,2024-08-02 08:14:33
  20.5666675,2024-08-02 08:15:33
  20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:16:33
  20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:17:33
  20.5000000,2024-08-02 08:18:33
  20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:19:33
  20.4666671,2024-08-02 08:20:33
  20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:21:33
  20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:22:33
  20.4000015,2024-08-02 08:23:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 08:24:33
  20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:25:33
  20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:26:33
  20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:27:33
  20.3666667,2024-08-02 08:28:33
  20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:29:33
  20.3000011,2024-08-02 08:30:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:31:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:32:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:33:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:34:33
  20.2666664,2024-08-02 08:35:33
  20.1666660,2024-08-02 08:36:33
  20.1666660,2024-08-02 08:37:33
  20.1333332,2024-08-02 08:38:33
  20.1333332,2024-08-02 08:39:33
  20.0666675,2024-08-02 08:40:33
  20.0666675,2024-08-02 08:41:33
  19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:42:33
  19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:43:33
  19.9333343,2024-08-02 08:44:33
  19.9666671,2024-08-02 08:45:33
  19.9000015,2024-08-02 08:46:33
  19.8666667,2024-08-02 08:47:33
  19.8000011,2024-08-02 08:48:33
  19.7666664,2024-08-02 08:49:33
  19.7333335,2024-08-02 08:50:33
  19.6666660,2024-08-02 08:51:33
  19.6666660,2024-08-02 08:52:33
  19.6000003,2024-08-02 08:53:33
  19.6000003,2024-08-02 08:54:33
  19.5666675,2024-08-02 08:55:33
  19.5333347,2024-08-02 08:56:33
  19.5333347,2024-08-02 08:57:33
  19.5000000,2024-08-02 08:58:33
  19.4333343,2024-08-02 08:59:33
  19.4333343,2024-08-02 09:00:33
  19.4666671,2024-08-02 09:01:33
  19.4333343,2024-08-02 09:02:33
  19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:03:33
  19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:04:33
  19.3666667,2024-08-02 09:05:33
  19.3333339,2024-08-02 09:06:33
  19.3000011,2024-08-02 09:07:33
  19.2666664,2024-08-02 09:08:33
  19.2666664,2024-08-02 09:09:33
  19.2000007,2024-08-02 09:10:33
  19.1666660,2024-08-02 09:11:33
  19.1666679,2024-08-02 09:12:33
  19.1333332,2024-08-02 09:13:33
  19.1333332,2024-08-02 09:14:33
  19.0666675,2024-08-02 09:15:33
  19.0333328,2024-08-02 09:16:33
  19.0333328,2024-08-02 09:17:33
  18.9666671,2024-08-02 09:18:33
  19.0000000,2024-08-02 09:19:33
  18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:20:33
  18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:21:33
  18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:22:33
  18.8999996,2024-08-02 09:23:33
  18.8333339,2024-08-02 09:24:33
  18.8333339,2024-08-02 09:25:33
  18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:26:33
  18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:27:33
  18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:28:33
  18.7666664,2024-08-02 09:29:33
  18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:30:33
  18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:31:33
  18.7333335,2024-08-02 09:32:33
  18.6666660,2024-08-02 09:33:33
  18.6333332,2024-08-02 09:34:33
  18.6333332,2024-08-02 09:35:33
  18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:36:33
  18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:37:33
  18.5666675,2024-08-02 09:38:33
  18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:39:33
  18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:40:33
  18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:41:33
  18.5333328,2024-08-02 09:42:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:43:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:44:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:45:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:46:33
  18.4000015,2024-08-02 09:47:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:48:33
  18.4333343,2024-08-02 09:49:33
  18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:50:33
  18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:51:33
  18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:52:33
  18.3333339,2024-08-02 09:53:33
  18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:54:33
  18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:55:33
  18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:56:33
  18.2333335,2024-08-02 09:57:33
  18.2000007,2024-08-02 09:58:33
  18.2000007,2024-08-02 09:59:33
  18.1333332,2024-08-02 10:00:33
  18.1333332,2024-08-02 10:01:33`;
  
  // data is originally from csv
  // // Fetch and process the CSV data
  // fetch("data.csv")
  //   .then((response) => response.text())
  //   .then((csv) => {
  //     const { temperatures, timestamps } = parseCSV(csv);
  //     createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps);
  //   });
  
  function parseCSV(csv) {
    const rows = csv.trim().split("\n");
    const temperatures = [];
    const timestamps = [];
  
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      const [temp, timestamp] = row.split(",");
      temperatures.push(parseFloat(temp));
      timestamps.push(timestamp);
    });
  
    return { temperatures, timestamps };
  }
  
  const { temperatures, timestamps } = parseCSV(csv);
  createLineChart(temperatures, timestamps);
.container {
    width: 100%;
}


.scrollable {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 300%;
}

canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 400px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <!-- Header content -->
        </header>

        <main>
            <div class="scrollable">
                <canvas id="temperatureChart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
           <p></p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <!-- Chart.js CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns@3.0.0"></script>
</body>

</html>




Thanks for this, but my problem is I have to make sure that it will only consume the height of the screen, right now, I'm having a vertical scroll.

@ramedju That is also easily achievable by adding height: 85vh !important to canvas but it does not look nice.

I have tried using  height: 100vh !important; this seems to looks good, my question now is, do you happen to know how to achieve that each data entry will have its own vertical line?

@ramedju what sort of vertical line you are talking about ?

For the time data, as you can see they are too compressed on each interval.

@ramedju I dont think that can be done but you should create new question about that maybe someone can help with that also you can read chartjs docs for that. If you think above of my response is useful then accept it as answer so that it will help people with similar issue.
